# "'data(...).options' is null or not an object" in jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui 1.8, and getting this error in Internet Explorer:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 10 May 2010 06:26:48 UTC


Message: 'data(...).options' is null or not an object
Line: 75
Char: 13074
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:58365/Scripts/Lib/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js
```

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?
The error happens when I use droppable/draggable.

Answer (score 3):

Try couple of things:

If you tried the `ready` handler but still got this error, try the `load` even instead:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code here
});
```

Or try putting your jquery/js code at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

In *jquery.min.js* replace:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var o = $(this).data('draggable').options;
    if (o._cursor) $('body').css("cursor", o._cursor);
}
```

With:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).data('draggable')) {
        var o = $(this).data('draggable').options;
        if (o._cursor) $('body').css("cursor", o._cursor);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my version it was not exactly the same syntax ('d(this).data("draggable")') but it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111918/replacewith-and-jquery-draggable-drop). I had something similar, because in our drop-function, we did `ui.draggable.remove()`. This meant jQuery had nothing to work on anymore.

Comment: I had this problem with a remove in a drop. It is an IE8 specific problem, in IE9 everything was working fine.